# iOS - making a cross-platform debugging variable macro

Tags: android, iphone, ios, logging, nslog

I got a macro I am using for debugging/logging, simply:

```
MY_DEBUG_INFO(msg...)
```

this works fine on say android:

```
#ifdef ANDROID
#define MY_DEBUG_INFO(msg...) __android_log(ANDROID_INFO,"TEST",msg...)   (roughly)
```

However, how do I make the same macro apply to iOS logging? With the new data types and all

```
#ifdef IOS
#define MY_DEBUG_INFO(msg...) NSLog(????)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#define MY_DEBUG_INFO(...) NSLog(@__VA_ARGS__)
```

Comment: Close, but the string type won't match if you're not using @"" for the Android code. May need to do some fiddly conversion from C strings in the macro, unfortunately.